# StreamSend API Blast, Sending Email

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I need to use StreamSend API to send email, here is 
[StreamSend API Reference](http://app.streamsend.com/docs/api/index.html)

I am making web request as post to following URL with proper credentials

https://app.streamsend.com/audiences/2/blasts.xml

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.Append("https://app.streamsend.com/audiences/2/blasts.xml");
            Uri uri = new Uri(sb.ToString());
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";

            StringBuilder strMail= new StringBuilder();
            strMail.Append("<blast> ALL from api..... </blast>");

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMail.ToString());
        Stream input = request.GetRequestStream();
        input.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        input.Close();
        HttpWebResponse nsResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

i am having err# 422 or 500. i would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Jim i already did credentials and input data. problem is error # 500, 422

Comment: You didn't show the credentials in your code sample, and you don't show that you're doing a POST request. In any event, according to the documentation you linked, 422 means that you supplied invalid data. 500, it says, is a problem with the StreamSend application. Are you checking the returned data from the 422 to see what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. First, it looks like you're trying to do a POST request (you're sending data in the request stream). If you really want a POST request, you have to set `request.Method = "POST";`

Also, if you want an XML response, you need to set the `Accept` header. According to the documentation you listed, you need: `request.Accept = "application/xml";`

And you need to add your login id to the request, as well. I'm not sure how that's done. Perhaps in the `request.Credentials` property like this:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login_id", "your_key_here");
```

Finally, there's no reason to use `StringBuilder` if all you're doing is assigning strings. You can write, for example:

```
string urlString = "https://app.streamsend.com/audiences/2/blasts.xml" 
Uri uri = new Uri(urlString);
```

or

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<blast> ALL from api..... </blast>");
```